# How to write css selector for button when all buttons have same details

Tags: java, selenium

[image: How to write css selector for this button Picking out]

I am having issue to write proper selector for this button "Picking out". on this page there are 5 to 6 buttons with same details but I want to click on first button with appropriate css selector.

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? Have it to be CSS Selector or we can also use XPath?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately I cannot use link because it is private with user credentials. yes xpath can also be option but preference is css selector.

Comment: OK, can you share the unique locator that matches these 5-6 buttons?